# how to resize-to-limit already saved img?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, rmagick

I uploaded images by using CarrierwaveUploader and I wanted to `resize_to_limit` so I enabled RMagick in Carrierwave.

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::RMagick
    storage :file

    def store_dir
      ...
    end

    def filename
      ...
    end

    version :thumb do
      process :resize_to_limit => [400, 400]
    end
end
```

Newly uploaded images are `resized-to-limit`, but i don't know how to apply `resize-to-limit` for already saved images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want the `recreate_versions!` command

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#recreating-versions